# How to wait for the other end of a named pipe to be open?

Tags: c++, c, unix, posix, named-pipes

I would like to exchange data between 2 processes (`A` and `B`) using 2 named pipes (`a2b` and `b2a`) as follows:

1. Process `A` creates the `a2b` and `b2a` pipes using `mkfifo(3)`.
2. Process `A` starts process `B` (either using `fork()`, `exec*()` or even `system()`)
3. `A` waits until `B` `open()`s `a2b` and `b2a`
4. `A` `write()`s data to `a2b`
5. `B` `read()`s data from `a2b`
6. `B` `write()`s data to `b2a`
7. `A` `read()`s data from `b2a`

**How can I make process `A` wait until process `B` `open()`s the other ends of the named pipes? -- i.e. How do I implement step 3?**

EDIT 1: As mentioned by @EJP, it is possible to implement step 3 using read/write/select. However, I would like to know if there are other approaches.

Comment: it would be better for B to write something to A first, just a Hello message. Then A could just block in the corresponding read, or  `select()` on the pipe for readability.

Comment: I agree that it is a possible approach. However, I don't want to use read/write to determine whether the other end is open. (I should have made this clear in my post)

Comment: So you want something that tells you when another process has opened a file descriptor in its private address space? I don't think that is possible, apart from say polling /proc/PID_PROCESSB/fd and looking for the pipe. Otherwise you could ask PROCESS B to signal you when it is ready, but there is no mechanism to my knowledge to communicate this information over fifos

Comment: Interesting. Could you post an answer with some code for doing that? (i.e. polling `/proc/process_b/fd` for the named pipes. TBH I'm not fond of using signals)

Comment: UNIX Domain sockets might be more suitable. You can use `select()` and then check whether an `accept()` occurred. When the other end of the "*pipe*" (*the socket*) connects, select in this end returns and you can check that.

Comment: You don't want to use read/write *why*?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi That may be. However, other aspects of my application require named pipes. (also, I'd like to know more about what can be done with named pipes)

Comment: If process A is starting process B can't you just use `pipe`?

Comment: @865719 - don't go down the proc path, change the kernel if you must. But its not that hard, you just monitor the directory fd and check when links are created. Epoll on a directory does this. Hope that points you in the right direction

Comment: @jam3st none of that is necessary at all

Comment: @dcow a lot of things are not necessary. Let him do as he pleases.

Comment: @jam3st I'm all for that, but there _is_ an actual solution this case that doesn't require kernel changes...

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of [POSIX open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is specified for FIFOs. If you're using Linux, [`man 7 fifo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) has some nice discussion:

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special
>      file that is opened by at least one process.  The FIFO must be opened
>      on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed.
>      Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.
>
> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening
>      for read-only succeeds even if no one has opened on the write side
>      yet and opening for write-only fails with ENXIO (no such device or
>      address) unless the other end has already been opened.

So you have two options:

1. use blocking mode and the `open` call will block till the other end is open, or
2. use non-blocking mode and spin on the `open` call until it succeeds.

If your requirements permit, you can skip a named pipe (FIFO) altogether and just use a [`pipe`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe). The child process inherits open file descriptors to each end of the pipe and can use either one as needed (don't forget to close the unneeded descriptor).

---

However, considering your end goal is bi-directional communication, might I suggest a ([unix domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)) [`socket`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) and some IO multiplexing strategy ([`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html), [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html), `epoll`, `kqueue`, etc.)?

Comment: A key point is that the two processes must cooperate by opening the two FIFOs in the same sequence — they must both open `a2b` before `b2a` or vice versa.  If one opens `a2b` and the other opens `b2a` first, then they get deadlocked — the first is waiting for the other to open `a2b` while the second is waiting for the other to open `b2a` and both are hung until the other does what is expected.